# How to add my own field on schema in fastapi users library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, fastapi-crudrouter, fastapiusers

I am using a library called [fastapi users](https://fastapi-users.github.io/fastapi-users/10.1/configuration/schemas/#adding-your-own-fields) for user authentication it's working fine but can't add extra field like they shown [here](https://fastapi-users.github.io/fastapi-users/10.1/configuration/schemas/#adding-your-own-fields)

I used this [example](https://fastapi-users.github.io/fastapi-users/10.1/configuration/full-example/) with sql alchemy
Here is my code

```
import uuid

from fastapi_users import schemas, models
from typing import List, Optional
import datetime
from fastapi import Request


class UserRead(schemas.BaseUser[uuid.UUID]):
    pass


class UserCreate(schemas.BaseUserCreate):
    first_name: str
    


class UserUpdate(schemas.BaseUserUpdate):
    # name: Optional[str]
    pass
```

Getting the error which says **TypeError: 'first_name' is an invalid keyword argument for User**

This is the route

```
app.include_router(fastapi_users.get_register_router(UserRead, UserCreate), prefix="/auth", tags=["auth"],)
```

The function of that route

```
    def get_register_router(
        self, user_schema: Type[schemas.U], user_create_schema: Type[schemas.UC]
    ) -> APIRouter:
        """
        Return a router with a register route.

        :param user_schema: Pydantic schema of a public user.
        :param user_create_schema: Pydantic schema for creating a user.
        """
        return get_register_router(
            self.get_user_manager, user_schema, user_create_schema
        )
```

And this is get register router

```
def get_register_router(
    get_user_manager: UserManagerDependency[models.UP, models.ID],
    user_schema: Type[schemas.U],
    user_create_schema: Type[schemas.UC],
) -> APIRouter:
    """Generate a router with the register route."""
    router = APIRouter()

    @router.post(
        "/register",
        response_model=user_schema,
        status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
        name="register:register",
        responses={
            status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST: {
                "model": ErrorModel,
                "content": {
                    "application/json": {
                        "examples": {
                            ErrorCode.REGISTER_USER_ALREADY_EXISTS: {
                                "summary": "A user with this email already exists.",
                                "value": {
                                    "detail": ErrorCode.REGISTER_USER_ALREADY_EXISTS
                                },
                            },
                            ErrorCode.REGISTER_INVALID_PASSWORD: {
                                "summary": "Password validation failed.",
                                "value": {
                                    "detail": {
                                        "code": ErrorCode.REGISTER_INVALID_PASSWORD,
                                        "reason": "Password should be"
                                        "at least 3 characters",
                                    }
                                },
                            },
                        }
                    }
                },
            },
        },
    )
    async def register(
        request: Request,
        user_create: user_create_schema,  # type: ignore
        user_manager: BaseUserManager[models.UP, models.ID] = Depends(get_user_manager),
    ):
        try:
            created_user = await user_manager.create(
                user_create, safe=True, request=request
            )
        except exceptions.UserAlreadyExists:
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
                detail=ErrorCode.REGISTER_USER_ALREADY_EXISTS,
            )
        except exceptions.InvalidPasswordException as e:
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
                detail={
                    "code": ErrorCode.REGISTER_INVALID_PASSWORD,
                    "reason": e.reason,
                },
            )

        return user_schema.from_orm(created_user)

    return router
```

Error:

```
INFO:     127.0.0.1:58852 - "POST /auth/register HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shayon/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 401, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "/home/shayon/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 78, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/shayon/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 269, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/shayon/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 124, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/shayon/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/home/shayon/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/home/shayon/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/cors.py", line 92, in __call__
    await self.simple_response(scope, receive, send, request_headers=headers)
  File "/home/shayon/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/cors.py", line 147, in simple_response
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/shayon/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 93, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/home/shayon/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/home/shayon/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__
    raise e
  File "/home/shayon/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/shayon/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 670, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/shayon/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 266, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/shayon/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 65, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/home/shayon/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 227, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "/home/shayon/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 160, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
  File "/home/shayon/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi_users/router/register.py", line 57, in register
    created_user = await user_manager.create(
  File "/home/shayon/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi_users/manager.py", line 143, in create
    created_user = await self.user_db.create(user_dict)
  File "/home/shayon/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi_users_db_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 129, in create
    user = self.user_table(**create_dict)
  File "<string>", line 4, in __init__
  File "/home/shayon/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 482, in _initialize_instance
    manager.dispatch.init_failure(self, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/shayon/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/home/shayon/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 208, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/shayon/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 479, in _initialize_instance
    return manager.original_init(*mixed[1:], **kwargs)
  File "/home/shayon/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/decl_base.py", line 1163, in _declarative_constructor
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: 'first_name' is an invalid keyword argument for User
```

Comment: I guess you have to add the `first_name` field to all three user models, as per the docs you linked https://fastapi-users.github.io/fastapi-users/10.1/configuration/schemas/#adding-your-own-fields

Comment: tried that still not working

Comment: show us the code where the error comes from

Comment: show the full traceback

Comment: Added that in the boy of the question

Comment: field needs to also be added to `User` model, not just the schema classes, see the note at the bottom of that docs page: "Make sure to mirror this in your database model"